# Snack Bar with Navigation Drawer Activity not working?

Tags: android, null, android-coordinatorlayout, navigation-drawer, snackbar

I'm using Snack Bar in Main Activity whose XML is activity_main.xml and its a navigation Drawer Activity and i have coordinator layout on content_main.xml but when i m initiating it in snack Bar make() it shows error and i came to know that my coordinatorLayout is null

```
coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorMainActivity);

if(coordinatorLayout != null) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Internet Connection Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

            snackbar.show();
        }
```

I don't know why it null, i m also using other contents of content_main.xml in MainActivity.java they are working but coordinator layout is null

Comment: Could you try without checking if it's null ? just the `SnakeBar` initialization? Also, Where do you try these codes? It should be in the `OnCreate` as u know..Show us where you are trying to show the SnakeBar please.

Answer (score -1):

Here I found one solution.

Just need to create a simple `<view/>` in the `activity_main.xml`.
Don't worry, it won't disturb the layout design.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then initialize the view in `onCreate()`.

`view = findViewById(R.id.view_main);`

Then show your `Snackbar`

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Internet Connection Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Happy coding!!!